# App with Embed segues on iOS 5.0 and below

Tags: ios, app-store

I have an app on the app store which **Requires iOS 5.0 or later**. I just loaded my project with Xcode 5, and I saw the error message **Class Unavailable   Embed segues are not available on iOS 5.1 and prior**. Does this imply that any users who are still using iOS 5.0 and below could download the app but it is not usable because of the embedded segues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Embed segues on iOS 5 it will crash the app. You should replace that by adding the embedded `ViewController` as `childViewController` and it's `view` as `subview`.